# Insert usando tabela temporaria apenas em valores que nao existem na tabela principal

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um insert em uma tabela usando uma outra tabela temporária, porem o insert somente poderá ocorrer se o item não existir na tabela original.

```
create temp table tmp_x as select * from solicitacao_materiais limit 0;
```

meu insert esta assim.

```
insert into solicitacao_materiais(codigo_material,quantidade_estoque,descricao_material,almoxarifado_relacionamento_id)
select codigo_material,quantidade_estoque,descricao_material,almoxarifado_relacionamento_id
from tmp_x
where solicitacao_materiais.codigo_material != tmp_x.codigo_material;
```

Estou usando o **codigo_material** para fazer a comparação pois cada item tem um cogido único e além da tabela temporária não dar os id's aos itens
porem estou recebendo o seguinte erro.

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "solicitacao_materiais"
>   LINE 4: where solicitacao_materiais.codigo_material != tmp_x.codigo_...
>                 ^
>   HINT:  There is an entry for table "solicitacao_materiais", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Alguem saberia me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Já tentou colocar no seu Where uma subconsulta ? 
where not(tmp_x.codigo_material in (select codigo_material from solicitacao_materiais))

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcao da sua query, use `where EXISTS`:

```
insert into solicitacao_materiais(codigo_material,quantidade_estoque,descricao_material,almoxarifado_relacionamento_id)
select codigo_material,quantidade_estoque,descricao_material,almoxarifado_relacionamento_id
from tmp_x
where EXISTS( SELECT codigo_material FROM solicitacao_materiais WHERE codigo_material != tempx.codigo_material );
```

exemplo minimal:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bedf34/1